# Chatter publisher not displayed in visualforce page when using filter on FeedItemType

Tags: visualforce, chatter

I've got a simple visualforce page and I would like to include the ability for user to post to chatter on it via the chatter:feed component.

When I include the chatter:feed tag with no attributes, the feed takes over the page.  I cant find a way to limit the length or verbosity of the feed.

Based on the documentation, it looks like I should be able to filter by feeditemtype and I believe that should limit the number or records.

The [vf dev documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_chatter_feed.htm) says:

> The feed item type on which the Entity or UserProfileFeed is filtered.
>   See FeedItem in the Object Reference for Salesforce and Force.com
>   (under Type) for accepted values.

The [FeedItem object reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_feeditem.htm) has a large number of options for type, but this one looked right:

> TextPost—a direct text entry on a feed.

So putting this together, i tried adding a parameter to chatter:feed for feeditemtype = "TextPost" but **then I get nothing - no publisher or feed displayed on page at all.**

Edit: I also tried including the showpublisher = true, with feeditemtype = textpost, but that ended up w/ no publisher/feed at all.

I suppose I could set entity ID to be an activity or some record w no feed, but would like to figure out why this is not working as it appears like it should.

code snippet- vf page with no filter displays publisher.  if feedItemType="TextPost" is added - no publisher is displayed at all.

```
<apex:outputPanel >
<p>Exercise 6 - Request Full Profile</p>
<apex:outputPanel rendered="TRUE">REQUEST UPDATE BELOW
<chatter:feed Entityid="{!User.Id}" showPublisher="TRUE"/>
</apex:outputPanel>
```

output (goes on well beyond the end of the screenshot)

[image: visualforce page w chatter feed]